# How do a simultaneous ascending and descending sort in KDB/Q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

In SQL, one can do

```
SELECT from tbl  ORDER BY col1, col2 DESC
```

In KDB, one can do

```
`col1 xasc select from tbl
```

or

```
`col2 xdesc select from tbl
```

But how does one sort by col1 ascending then by col2 descending in KDB/Q?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 sorts.

Create example data:

```
q)show tbl:([]a:10?10;b:10?10;c:10?10)
a b c
-----
8 4 8
1 9 1
7 2 9
2 7 5
4 0 4
5 1 6
4 9 6
2 2 1
7 1 8
8 8 5
```

Do sorting:

```
q)`a xasc `b xdesc tbl
a b c
-----
1 9 1
2 7 5
2 2 1
4 9 6
4 0 4
5 1 6
7 2 9
7 1 8
8 8 5
8 4 8
```

Comment: I think that this is clearer:

I think that this is clearer, but that appears to work.

  `tbl2:([]a:(til 10) mod 3 ;b: til 10; row:til 10)
  `a xasc `b xdesc  tbl2

Comment: Sure - this creates a larger set size in a so the effect is more apparent.  Don't forget ` on a.

Comment: I dont think you are correct. Using @gbronner 's tbl2: `q)(\`a xasc tbl2) ~ (\`a xasc \`b xdesc tbl2)
0b`